# Calculating confidence intervals around lme.dscore Cohen's D for mixed effect models in nlme

Tags: r, nlme

I have a mixed effects model that I have calculated effect size using the package EMA tools and lme.dscore. However this only returns a single value of d and I would like the upper and lower CI as well. Is there a way to calculate this?

Thank you

```
library(EMAtools)
lme.dscore(bm.lme1,data=matched.cases3, type="nlme")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that Cohen's D is calculated as (2 * t-value)/sqrt(*df*)

And t-values are calculated as β/*SE(β)*

You can use confint(bm.lme1,method="Wald") to get confidence intervals for β, and from that calculate confidence intervals for Cohen's D.